# Is there a way to rehabilitate a reputation of 1 or am I doomed to eternal darkness?

Tags: discussion

My first question here was judged deficient and so the traditional capital-punishment-for-jaywalking penalty was assessed.

If it's not possible, let me know and I'll try to somehow live a meaningful life anyway ;-)

PS: feel free to penalise me as many points as you wish for this question.

Comment: I'm curious to read your first question but I am not able to find it. Anyhow, I have voted your post so that I hope you get an higher reputation. :)

Answer (score 1):

The lowest your reputation can be is 1. Yes you can still attain reputation.

The system automatically deletes closed questions after some time and rep lost on these questions are refunded. I (phwd) just did a recalculation of your rep. So now you have 6. In a little while the change will be reflected in meta.webapps (meta rep is tied into site rep on all sites) and you can ask questions here as well. I assumed you wanted to know about webapps.stackexchange even though you tagged the question stackoverflow.